# Change user used to access database connected to django website in runtime

Tags: python, django, postgresql, authentication

Currently I implemented a login routine for the website I am working on, according to [This Tutorial](https://wsvincent.com/django-user-authentication-tutorial-login-and-logout/).

Also I am not authenticating the user with djangos own system, because I am using authentication against the LDAP of my company ([django-auth-ldap](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

Currently I am using a general user to login to the database, which has universal access to all data, which also gives full access to any user logging in to the website.

To avoid that I would like to know how I can connect to the database as the **individual** user, who just logged in to the website.

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1):

Restricting user access to functionality and authenticating with the DB are handled separately in Django. You might be able to read the privileges of your users from the DB and map them to Django permissions but this is non-trivial (about Permissions see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

In a UI/UX that has functionalities restricted depending on authorization, the frontend and backend need to be aware that permissions need to be checked and missing authorization needs to be communicated in some way or other to the user.

Example:

Users in group A are allowed to delete X. They see the "delete" button and there might also be an AJAX call that can delete X.

Users in group B are not allowed to delete X. They do not see the delete button and the AJAX call that can delete X needs to check for that permission and/or user group membership.

If you are only using a DB level authorization layer than - how would you know if the "delete" button should be displayed and for what to check in the AJAX call?

Comment: The restrictions on accessing the data from the database are managed in the DBMS itself, i just need a way to log in different users to the database in runtime, so the requests send from django are send as this user.

Answer (score 0):

hi!
If I'm getting your problem correctly, the user you are creating is a Super User every time right?

Well if you are using Django `auth.User` model, you can just make `User_object.is_super` to `False` and then restrict the access of users though if-else in view! (User_object is the object of the auth.User model)

Does that made any sense?

//BTW, a side-note, a mistake I made while making my first custom user model: make sure to store your passwords hashed using Django hashes and salts!

Comment: Django stores you passwords automatically hashed? Use `User.objects.create_user()` and `create_superuser()`, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation

Comment: The backend i use for authentication is django-auth-ldap, this brings login functionality to your website, without needing to care for stuff like storing passwords etc, because you are in fact authenticating against an external LDAP server.